# ByteBuddy AgentBuilder Problems setting a Hook to KafkaListenerContainerFactory

Tags: java, hook, byte-buddy

I am trying to set a method Hook to KafkaListenerContainerFactory.KafkaListenerContainerFactory()
I am having problems defining the method signature and always get the error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of
[private static net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder CompanyURL.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessorHook.lambda$install$0(net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder,net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription,java.lang.ClassLoader,net.bytebuddy.utility.JavaModule),
public static java.lang.Object CompanyURL.KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessorHook.createListenerContainer(java.lang.Object,java.util.concurrent.Callable)
throws java.lang.Exception, INSTANCE] allows for delegation from public abstract org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListenerContainer org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory.createListenerContainer(org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method in question returns [a `MessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/KafkaListenerContainerFactory.html#createListenerContainer(org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpoint)), not a smart life cycle.

Interceptors can only return an assignable type, that's why your possible interceptor is not considered.